# NetworkingError: getaddrinfo EMFILE dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443

Tags: node.js, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

There is a table say company. If we try to get the company by it primary key we get the following error. 
PLEASE NOTE: This error is not for all instances. It is not repeatedly getting failed. It occurs sometimes but often. 20% of requests are failing

```
{ Error: getaddrinfo EMFILE dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443
at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at errnoException (dns.js:55:15)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
message: 'getaddrinfo EMFILE dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com:443',
code: 'NetworkingError',
errno: 'EMFILE',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
host: 'dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com',
port: 443,
region: 'eu-west-1',
retryable: true,
time: 2019-07-18T05:30:09.145Z }
```

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 2):

There was a discussion on [aws](https://github.com/aws)/[aws-sdk-js-v3](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3) with issue [#3019](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/3019) where it was recommended to lower the socket timeouts.

This happened to me too when I used the agent as below

```
new https.Agent({
  keepAlive: true,
  maxSockets: Infinity,
}
```

Then I looked more into the documentation here at [Reusing Connections with Keep-Alive in Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/node-reusing-connections.html) and what I found was an interesting thing

> The easiest way to configure SDK for JavaScript to reuse TCP connections is to set the `AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED` environment variable to `1`. This feature was added in the [2.463.0](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#24630) release.

So, I removed the `httpsAgent` from the AWS DynamoDBClient connection and added the required environment variable -

```
AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: 1
```

The error was resolved and things were working as expected.

I hope somebody might find this answer helpful.

Comment: I don't think sdk v3 support this option tho:  AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was double checking the region. My region had a 0.
solution was using:

```
  region: 'eu-west-1',
```

instead of:

```
  region: 'eu-west-01',
```